# BMW rims on a Terrain?

Tags: wheels

I have a Chevy Terrain, and asked the local dealer to put my snows on - they are on BMW rims.  I was told they wouldn't as this was a safety issue.  The rims would only sit on the edge of the bolt, and not securely on the entire surface.  I got them from a tire specialist last year, who says they are safe.
Confused and would appreciate some help.

Comment: There are different types of bolts used for wheels.  Maybe you have the wrong type?  Also, there are a lot of variables to wheel size.  It would be nice if you could get a more technical reason from the installer that said they would not be safe.  If someone says that it isn't safe, it would be best to really understand why rather than trying to find someone else that will do it.

Comment: Have you already had them on the vehicle before? Do you have pictures describing better exactly what you're talking about? Rims don't usually sit on bolts (lugs?). Even if you mean the lugs, the wheels shouldn't be sitting on them, either.

Comment: @JanK Wheels are only safe if they can be properly attached to your specific vehicle. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a brief list of things to consider when using wheels from a different vehicle:

1. **Bolt pattern** Different vehicles have different bolt patterns, and different spacing between the bolts (also called lugs). This is most often described as (number of bolts)x(bolt spacing). 4x100, 5x135, etc. These need to be an exact match, otherwise the wheel will not fit onto the bolts at all.
2. **Offset** This is the most often neglected aspect of wheel sizing and possibly what's going on here with your BMW wheels not fitting safely to your Chevy. Basically, (as indicated in the picture below) some vehicles need the wheel to stick out further away from the brakes than others (called negative or lower offset), some vehicles need the wheel to sit a lot closer to the brakes than others (called positive or higher offset). Having the incorrect offset will cause your wheels to either rub against something (fender, suspension or brakes) or stick way too far out od the vehicle (that's a ticket in most places).
   [image]
   [image]
3. **Hub size** The hub is the round piece of metal that sticks out of the vehicle's hub and goes through the big hole at the centre of the wheel. It needs to be the correct size, otherwise the wheel won't sit properly.